# what is the best way for caching frequently changing status information?

Tags: grails

my projects deals with a client / server structure where the clients provide status information via a soap interface in a periodically way. every request (1 per minuete) contains a complex stucture of stat us data.

status information is used by many views and instead fetching the information each time from database i store the data in a sychronized list.

are there better caching techniques in grails? are sychronized lists a good solution?

Comment: You ask are there "better caching techniques"? can you let us know if there is a particular problem you are having with your current solution? is it under-performing? or is it just that you'd prefer to use a tried-and-true approach rather than roll-your-own?

Comment: my solution deals with following problem: poor search possibilities when using very complex objects (my current structrue looks like this: map<id,<ComplexOject>>). i would also like to know if there better alternatives to synchronized lists, e.g. ehcache, in-memory databases for caching purposes,..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems more like a generalized question so I'll provide some generalized thoughts form my own experience.

**Are there better caching techniques in grails? are sychronized lists a good solution?**

There may be several layers of cache depending on what your dealing with.  I don't believe bare-bones grails itself caches anything with regard to your question however; there are configurable options and plugins that allow you to cache everything from queries, domain classes, service calls, page fragment, images, css and just about everything else.  Not to mention your database and other layers may have their own cache options.

Having said that I would **avoid using your own caching techniques unless your dealing with a very specific issue** where you know you can perform better than a more generic approach like a second level cache (ie EHCache).

**If you do roll your own** cache you'll want to **be aware** of everything else that might be caching the same content as well.  Caching a cached object form a cached query is a tough one to debug.

If performance is your concern you should always do some bench marking before you change anything.  **To truly get the best performance out of anything you'll need to understand how it works.**  Grails, hibernate and spring work together on performance and this isn't anything I can put in few sentences but there are plugins that can help you understand  what is going on beyond the scenes like [JavaMelody](http://grails.org/plugin/grails-melody).

Lastly, if you already built something that works and everyone's happy don't break it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably a properly scoped service may help:
http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/services.html#scopedServices

Maybe a "session"-scoped service may be the thing you're looking for.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i'm searching for more detailed solution and best pratice concept. at the moment i use a service with a synchronized list to store this information.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the built-in caching techniques: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/ref/Database%20Mapping/cache.html

A more detailed way is described here: http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/single.html#caching

Depending on what you want to cache, you may want to use `Caching instances` (to cache everything of that instance) or `Caching Queries` (where you only cache the result of one query)

As you can see in the second link, the config lets you use `EhCache` as cache manager.